# Can adding a WebGL readPixels call change the output of shaders?

Tags: webgl

Is it possible to create a sequence of WebGL commands that gives a different output if a spurious readPixels command (writing to an otherwise unused buffer) is inserted into the middle of the program?

**Context**

I've run into a situation where I'm applying a series of shaders in WebGL, and they sometimes compute the wrong thing. Isolating the bug has proved extremely difficult because it seems to depend on random details of the shaders and the presence of certain calls that should be redundant. As far as I can tell, I am not doing anything wrong or even particularly out of the ordinary. I suspect a GPU driver bug, with some sort of race condition since it is not consistent how many iterations it takes to catch a bad result, but I could be a lot more confident in that inference if I knew that behavior when a readPixels line was present should match the behavior when it is not present.

For reference, this is code that reproduces the bug on my desktop (Windows, NVidia GeForce RTX 2060, AMD Ryzen 7 2700X). It does not reproduce on other machines I own:

```js
const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl');
const GL = WebGLRenderingContext;
{
    gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float');
    gl.getExtension('WEBGL_color_buffer_float');
    let positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    let positions = new Float32Array([-1, +1, +1, +1, -1, -1, +1, -1]);
    gl.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, positions, GL.STATIC_DRAW);
    let indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    let indices = new Uint16Array([0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1]);
    gl.bindBuffer(GL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(GL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, GL.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, 4, 2);
}

function shader(fragmentShaderSource) {
    let glVertexShader = gl.createShader(GL.VERTEX_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(glVertexShader, `
            precision highp float;
            precision highp int;
            attribute vec2 position;
            void main() {
              gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);
            }`);
    gl.compileShader(glVertexShader);

    let glFragmentShader = gl.createShader(GL.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(glFragmentShader, `
            precision highp float;
            precision highp int;
            ${fragmentShaderSource}`);
    gl.compileShader(glFragmentShader);

    let program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(program, glVertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(program, glFragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(program);

    gl.deleteShader(glVertexShader);
    gl.deleteShader(glFragmentShader);
    return program;
}

function tex() {
    let texture = gl.createTexture();
    let framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();

    gl.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(GL.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
    gl.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texImage2D(GL.TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.RGBA, 4, 2, 0, GL.RGBA, GL.FLOAT, null);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(GL.FRAMEBUFFER, GL.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

    return {texture, framebuffer};
}

let shader_less_than = shader(`
    uniform float lim;
    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(float(gl_FragCoord.y < lim), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }`);

let shader_zero = shader(`
    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }`);

let shader_tricky = shader(`
    uniform sampler2D tex_unused_dep;
    uniform sampler2D tex_c;

    void main() {
        float c = texture2D(tex_c, gl_FragCoord.xy / vec2(4.0, 2.0)).x;
        vec2 unused = texture2D(tex_unused_dep, vec2(0.0, c)).xy; // Without this line, test passes.
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, c, 0.0, 0.0);
    }`);

let tex_unrelated = tex();
let tex_lim = tex();
let tex_unused_dep = tex();
let tex_out = tex();
let out_buf = new Float32Array(32);

for (let k = 0; k < 1000; k++) {
    let flag = k % 2 === 0;

    gl.useProgram(shader_zero);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(GL.FRAMEBUFFER, tex_unused_dep.framebuffer);
    gl.drawElements(GL.TRIANGLES, 6, GL.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    gl.useProgram(shader_less_than);
    gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(shader_less_than, 'lim'), flag ? 1 : 2);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(GL.FRAMEBUFFER, tex_unrelated.framebuffer);
    gl.drawElements(GL.TRIANGLES, 6, GL.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(shader_less_than, 'lim'), flag ? 1 : 2);  // Commenting this line makes a pass more likely, but not guaranteed.
    gl.bindFramebuffer(GL.FRAMEBUFFER, tex_lim.framebuffer);
    gl.drawElements(GL.TRIANGLES, 6, GL.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    // gl.readPixels(0, 0, 4, 2, GL.RGBA, GL.FLOAT, out_buf); // Uncommenting this line seems to guarantee a pass.

    gl.useProgram(shader_tricky);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(shader_tricky, 'tex_unused_dep'), 0);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(shader_tricky, 'tex_c'), 1);
    gl.activeTexture(GL.TEXTURE0 + 0);
    gl.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, tex_unused_dep.texture);
    gl.activeTexture(GL.TEXTURE0 + 1);
    gl.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, tex_lim.texture);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.getAttribLocation(shader_tricky, 'position'));
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.getAttribLocation(shader_tricky, 'position'), 2, GL.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(GL.FRAMEBUFFER, tex_out.framebuffer);
    gl.drawElements(GL.TRIANGLES, 6, GL.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    gl.readPixels(0, 0, 4, 2, GL.RGBA, GL.FLOAT, out_buf);
    if (out_buf[17] !== (flag ? 0 : 1)) {
        throw new Error("Bad output.")
    }
}
console.log("PASS");
```

Comment: You said it only happens on one of your devices. But does it happen on all browsers on that device? chrome, ff, edge?

Comment: @zoran404 Happens in both chrome and firefox.

Comment: I read through your code, nothing out of the ordinary. And to answer your question, no, calling readPixels shouldn't affect the output. The only notable thing about readPixels is that it blocks execution of js, unlike the rest of the ql command which are async.

Comment: Have a look at the translated HLSL shader source using the [`WEBGL_debug_shaders`  extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WEBGL_debug_shaders), that unused dependent texture read should be optimized away either way. Maybe this is just a precision issue and the value you're checking against is something like .999999 or 1.000001 ?

Comment: I'm guessing this a bug in ANGLE and you could file something [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/angleproject/issues/list)

Comment: @LJ No, when the value is the wrong thing it's equal to zero.

Comment: @gman If it was a bug in angle, wouldn't it not reproduce in firefox?

Comment: [firefox uses angle](https://webglreport.com/)

Comment: I tested it in Edge and it didn't reproduce, which suggests Angle may be the cause. Reporting it there: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/angleproject/issues/detail?id=4657